# How to save a bluetooth connection to settings using CoreBluetooth and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a device I want to keep connected to my iPhone while the app I'm building is not running. Currently, I'm at the point where I connect to the bluetooth device, hop over to settings, and can see the device there (I'm using the Nordic Thingy for testing).

I know it is possible because I have a Bose app that does the same thing with my headphones: it doesn't need me to have the app open or even in the background for the headphones to work after I've connected to them via the app.

I've looked into how to persist the bluetooth connections with my team, but we've only found guides similar to this one on [how to save data in the background for autoconnection when the app is open again](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1), or guides on [how to work with bluetooth devices when your app is in the background](https://medium.com/@cbartel/ios-scan-and-connect-to-a-ble-peripheral-in-the-background-731f960d520d).

Is there a way to mimic Bose's behavior here?

Comment: There are two types of Bluetooth connections. Legacy Bluetooth for services like hands free/headsets and BLE. Bose headphones typically support both; the legacy for the audio and BLE for configuration.  The connection you see in settings is the legacy audio connection. For a BLE only device there will only be a connection while an app maintains a connection.  Why do you think you need to maintain a connection when your app isn't running?

Comment: I suppose I wasn't sure why Bose was able to do it and other things weren't. If you explain that in an answer I'd accept